# SPLIT or TRIM Text(String,Varchar) in MSSQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, sql-server-2017

i want to split or "trim" a Field(Name) in my SQL-Server in a table... But i got errors in every tried way.

Sample Error Code for my personal Better way Statement:

> The SingleWords column or the user-defined aggregate "SingleWords.value" was not found, or the name is ambiguous.

For Example:

Ive got a Field which called: "name". This field includes the forename & last name(separated with CR/LF or Space).

For my Statement, i need to split the name in two different Fields.. But I only want to use SQL-Management Studio..

Is this possible?

My SQL Compability Level is at "130"...

i tried the following Statement for Example:

```
SELECT NAME FROM dbo.CRM_IM_X STRING_SPLIT(Name, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)) WHERE RTRIM(NAME) <> '';
```

OR(My Personal better way):

```
SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(NAME,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS SingleWords
    FROM dbo.CRM_IM_X

SELECT SingleWords.value('x[1]','varchar(max)') AS part1
      ,SingleWords.value('x[2]','varchar(max)') AS part2
FROM dbo.CRM_IM_X
```

Part 1 for the Forename,

Part 2 for the Last name,

CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) for CR/LF.

SAMPLE DATA INPUT:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(NAME VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Jane
Doe'),('John
Doe');
```

But i got stucked in combining these 2 Select-Statements together...

Comment: Please tag your SQL Server version.

Comment: please provide sample data and output

Comment: Don't tag MySQL for a SQL Server question, They are not the same RDBMS.

Comment: On a different note, you say you got "errors". Please could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49730089/edit) your post and include them please?

Comment: just looking at your sample data, the first problem is that you have one person with a title, and then the second without one. This immediately poses a problem. Does this mean you could also have the following values? `Mr Smith`, `Mr George W Bush`,  unless you have a consistency to your data, you aren't going to achieve this. If you can't make safe assumptions, then you're going to get wrong results.

Comment: i already thought that... i edit my Statement, CR/LF is only between Forename and last name. May then it is possible?

if you Try following Statement:

{SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(NAME,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS SingleWords
    FROM dbo.CRM_IM_X}

You see, that the "x" stands in the right position... After that i want to try to put this in own Fields with following Statement:

{SELECT SingleWords.value('x[1]','varchar(max)') AS part1
      ,SingleWords.value('x[2]','varchar(max)') AS part2
FROM dbo.CRM_IM_X}

I Need these two Steps in one statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your new data (where you have no title), this can easily be achieved as the following:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(NAME VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Jane
Doe'),('John
Doe');

WITH Replaced AS(
    SELECT REPLACE([NAME],CHAR(13),'') AS [Name]
    FROM @tbl)
SELECT LEFT([name], CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),[Name]) -1) AS FirstName,
       RIGHT([name], LEN([Name]) - (CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),[Name]))) AS Surname
FROM Replaced;
```

The problem, however, as I discussed in the comments, is if you start having names that don't have only 2 parts. As an example, see what happens when we do so:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(NAME VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Jane
Doe'),
('John
Doe'),
('Mr
Smith'),
('Mr
Joe
Bloggs'),
('George
W.
Bush'),
('Sir
Friedrich
Harold
Smithe
III');

WITH Replaced AS(
    SELECT REPLACE([NAME],CHAR(13),'') AS [Name]
    FROM @tbl)
SELECT LEFT([name], CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),[Name]) -1) AS FirstName,
       RIGHT([name], LEN([Name]) - (CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),[Name])))
FROM Replaced;
```

Comment: Do You have an Idea how we can solve the problem wit "title" in the Fields? Is it possible to work with a if pattern?

Comment: @XaviLux in SQL server, honestly don't. [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Without **very** strict rules in place already, the best "thing" at splitting out a name, is a person (there's too many variables to programmatically decide); and if you had those rules you probably wouldn't be in the position you're in. :)

Comment: in this case i have a List with possible title combinations. There are about 20 titles in this Field(catalogEntry). So it would be possible, to create a Rule in SQL?

Comment: @XaviLux No, because in your original data you had someone with a title and no first name; so I already know that there aren't rules. By very strict, I literally mean **very strick**. If a name may or may not have a first name, that's already 1 too many variables.

Comment: you're right, i didn't realise, that sometimes the last name can also be missing in the field... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
// You can use the Common Table Expression(CTE).
;WITH Split_Names (SingleWords)
AS
(
   SELECT CONVERT(XML,'<Names><name>'  
                      + REPLACE(Names,' ', '</name><name>') 
                      + '</name></Names>'
                 ) AS SingleWords
   FROM ExampleTable
)

SELECT  SingleWords.value('/Names[1]/name[1]','varchar(100)') AS part1,    
        SingleWords.value('/Names[1]/name[2]','varchar(100)') AS part2,
        SingleWords.value('/Names[1]/name[3]','varchar(100)') AS part3
FROM Split_Names
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c4aa/1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Help! @Larnu Youre right, if CR/LF is also Used for Title you gonna get this Problem, if i only Use 2 Parts. But If i get an third Part & fourth Part, i think its possible, when the Name Syntax ist everytime like: Title(CR/LF),Forename(CR/LF),last name

if the Syntax isn't the same i need one more Step, to put the right information of the name to the right field i think?:

following Code has also worked now. This Sample will put each word before and after CR/LF in one new Field:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(NAME VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Jane
Doe'),
('John
Doe'),
('Mr
john
Smith'),
('Mr
Joe
Bloggs'),
('George
W.
Bush'),
('Sir
Friedrich
Harold
Smithe
III');

WITH Splitted AS
(
SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(NAME,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS SingleWords
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT SingleWords.value('x[1]','varchar(max)') AS part1
      ,SingleWords.value('x[2]','varchar(max)') AS part2
      ,SingleWords.value('x[3]','varchar(max)') AS part3
      ,SingleWords.value('x[4]','varchar(max)') AS part4
FROM Splitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple code given below:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Name)) AS PART1, 
       SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name), LEN(Name)) AS PART2 
FROM ExampleTable
```

I have added my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a064d/18) with this solution. You can check it. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you! @vignesh